# Best way on Android to show a persistent video player at the top of the screen in all screens?

Tags: android, video, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

This is an existing app with around 15 different activities. I need to have a video player that will keep playing at the top while the user can navigate throughout the app.

Is the only way to accomplish this by refactoring everything into a main activity and then just have the video player in a separate fragment? One added complication is that I need to support pager view activities but have the video player at the top that won't change when the user swipes through the pages.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use framelayout with video player and fragments below it which keeps changing

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same trick some apps (i.e. Facebook Messenger) are using - add a view to android.view.Window.

What will be different is that you would hide that view anytime user navigates away from your application.

It might not be the most elegant solution, but it'd keep changes to all your views to minimum.

See [this article](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/) for some samples.